# Textarea value undefined when using getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript

I stuck in a very simple thing that I need to do and I can't explain why is this happening. I have a `textarea` with no `id` or `class` or `name`, so the only way of selecting it with js is to use `getElementsByTagName`. It's the only `textarea` in my HTML so it's pretty obvious to use the following:

```
var theSrc = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value;
```

However, when alerting `theSrc` I always get `undefined`. Any ideas why is this happening?

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D3zBU/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you read the value when your script (which is in the HEAD of the page) is first read, before even the DOM is ready. Read the value in the function :

```
function displayValue() {
    var theSrc = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value;
    alert(theSrc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either write your js after the body or use

```
$().ready(function(){
    //code
});
```

as in head is loaded before the body so, variable "theSrc" has no idea about text area

Answer (score 1):

It is the matter where you are writing JavaScript it works fine when you write inside body tag.

```
<body>
--------textarea code
<script>
var theSrc = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value;
</script>
</body>
```

Now it will work. That's because of document priority execution.